# Sending the data to the server using HttpPost Request in android

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient

I am sending the string value to the php file on the server like this:

```
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("serverurl");
    Log.d("httppost..", httppost + "");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", dataCount + ""));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }
```

But, I am not seeing any data which I have sent from the app.
Thanks for any help.